# ANTLR4 Parser Error: no viable alternative at input

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

So I have a grammar I have been trying to write, based on a mix between (mainly) the Lua and C official ANTLR grammars. But I've run into an issue with parsing a table-like structure in a declaration block. It has been giving the "no viable alternative" error shown below:

```
Parser error (3, 14): no viable alternative at input 'cat_dog_table[]',<unknown>,3,13,true
```

The example code being parsed is shown below:

```
constants

cat_dog_table[]  [
    DOG_FISH_FOOD,                         CAT_FOOD_FISH | BIRD_WING_COW,                        TREE_DOG_FISH,
    TREE_CAT_FOOD,                         TREE_BIRD_DOG | TREE_TREE_DOG,                        TREE_CAT_TREE,
    ],

animal_table[]
[
// For future animals
],

endconstants
```

And my actual grammar:

```
grammar example; 

///////////////////////////
//      PARSER RULES     //
///////////////////////////

//starting rule
chunk 
    : block EOF
    ;

block 
    : stat* retstat?
    ;

//statements
stat
    : 'break'
    | funccall
    | decblock
    ;

//Necessary if pre-compiler statement interjects in the middle of a declaration block
precompstatblock
    : funclist | vallist | constlist | fieldlist | explist | namelist | block
    ;

//declaration blocks
decblock
    : 'fields' fieldlist* 'endfields'
    | 'constants' (('values_for' NAME vallist* 'endvalues')|constlist)* 'endconstants'
    ;

exp
    : 'NULL' | 'TRUE' | 'FALSE' | 'SUCCESS' | 'FAILURE' | 'INVALID'
    | tabledec
    | number
    | NAME
    | STRING
    | funccall
    ;

args
    : (explist | namelist | fieldlist | funccall | tableconstruct)+
    ;

funccall
    : NAME '(' args? ')'
    ;

constlist
    : tabledec (',' constlist?)?
    | vallist (',' constlist?)?
    | fieldlist (',' constlist?)?
    ;

explist
    : exp (',' exp?)*
    ;

fieldlist
    : NAME ':' ('[]')? NAME (number)? (',' fieldlist)?
    ;

funclist
    : funccall ('(' args? ')')? NAME? (',' (funccall ('(' args? ')')? NAME?)?)*
    ;

namelist
    : NAME (',' NAME?)*
    ;

vallist
    : NAME (number|NAME|exp) (',' (NAME (number|NAME|exp))?)*
    ;

//return statement
retstat
    : 'return' ('('explist')'|explist)?
    ;

number
    : INT | HEX | FLOAT
    ;

tabledec
    : NAME '[' (NAME|number|exp)? ']' '[' ((namelist|explist) ('|' (namelist|explist))*)? ']' (',' constlist?)?
    | NAME ':' '[]' NAME 'new' '[]' NAME tableconstruct
    ;

tableconstruct
    : '{' (explist|namelist|funclist)* '}' | '(' (explist|namelist|funclist)* ')'
    ;


///////////////////////////
//      LEXER RULES      //
///////////////////////////

INT
    : Digit+
    ;

HEX
    : '0' [xX] HexDigit+
    ;

FLOAT
    : Digit+ '.' Digit*
    | '.' Digit+
    ;

NAME
    : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
    ;

STRING
    : '"' (EscapeSequence|~('\\'|'"'))* '"'
    ;

fragment
Digit
    : [0-9]
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    : '\\' [abfnrtvz"'\\]
    | '\\' '\r'? '\n'
    ;

fragment
HexDigit
    : [0-9a-fA-F]
    ;

WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
        -> skip
    ;
```

I've read quite a bit online about other people's issues with this and it seems that maybe my parser is consuming the name token or something when going down a particular rule first, but then isn't able to match it to my table declaration rule when it tries an alternative because the name token is already consumed. But I'm really not sure. I've tried reordering things, checked to make sure that it wasn't a syntactical error but I haven't had any luck. I also tried moving tabledec into one of the alternatives in the decblock rule, like this:

```
decblock
    : 'fields' fieldlist* 'endfields'
    | 'constants' (tabledec|('values_for' NAME vallist* 'endvalues')|constlist)* 'endconstants'
    ;
```

However this caused the parser to parse everything as a statement and never find the end of the constants block, which is confusing to me in itself. I having a feeling that maybe I am making an obvious mistake here, but me staring at it for so long has made me oblivious to it.

Here is parse tree of the example text:
[image: overall parse tree]

[image: Zoom-in on location of error]

So as you can see, it seems to be looking for some sort of token that it's not finding. Which is weird to me because constlist should directly lead to tabledec, but for some reason the rule can't be found. I'm not quite sure what to do to fix this from here, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You're defining token '[' and '[]'. If you put a space between the open/close bracket in the input `[]` e.g., `[ ]`, it parses. You really should not define a token '[]'.

Comment: Remember, Antlr lexers work without any context from the parser. And the lexer will always choose (1) the token type with the longest string, and if two or more tokens match exactly the same string, the first token listed in the grammar will be chosen.